# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: null

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a reactjs sample code with material-ui and got below error.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: null.

Check the render method of `TransitionGroup`.
    in TransitionGroup (created by ForwardRef(TouchRipple))
    in span (created by ForwardRef(TouchRipple))
    in ForwardRef(TouchRipple)
    in ForwardRef(TouchRipple) (created by WithStyles(memo))
    in WithStyles(memo) (created by ForwardRef(ButtonBase))
    in button (created by ForwardRef(ButtonBase))
    in ForwardRef(ButtonBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase)) (created by ForwardRef(Button))
    in ForwardRef(Button) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Button)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Button)) (at Ranking.js:49)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(CardActions))
    in ForwardRef(CardActions) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardActions)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardActions)) (at Ranking.js:48)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    ...
    in Provider (at src/index.js:13)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
```

My code is like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography, Button, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Card } from '@material-ui/core';

export default class Ranking extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onMount(this.props.categoryId);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.categoryId !== nextProps.categoryId) {
            this.props.onUpdate(nextProps.categoryId);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { category, ranking, error } = this.props;
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>{typeof category !== 'undefined' ? `${category.name}`:''}</h2>
                {(() => {
                    return ranking.map((item, i) => (
                        <Card
                            key={`ranking-item-${item.code}`}
                            style={{ width: '400px', margin: '32px auto' }}
                        >
                            <CardMedia image={item.imageUrl} title={`${i + 1} ${item.name}`} style={{ height: '200px' }} />
                            <CardContent>
                                <Typography variant="body1">{`${i + 1} ${item.name}`}</Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                            <CardActions disableSpacing>
                                <Button>aaa</Button>
                                <button href={item.url} style={{width: '200px'}}>aa</button>
                            </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                    ));
                })()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If I remove `<Button>aaa</Button>`, this page shows without any error. I am confuced why this error happen. I would like to solve this issue. Could someone give me an advice?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you gluing too many things together Try

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice however, I still have same error....

Comment: what about  < button></button> ?

Comment: ```<button></button>``` is just replacement.
I got an error with ```<Button></Button>``` then tried with normal HTML tag ```<button></button>```.
I don't have any error when I use only ```<button></button>```.

Comment: try to chang <Button> with <button>

Comment: where are you use TransitionGroup ?

Comment: Thanks for checking again. I separated import as your advice. Still have same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue after installed react-transition-group.
I don't use Transition Group but need this package.